# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg' error

Tags: 16.04, dpkg, add-apt-repository

I run below command on ubuntu 16.4 :

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps`

of below question:

[How to install PlayOnLinux on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770687/how-to-install-playonlinux-on-ubuntu-16-04)

and get below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Try reinstalling the `python3-software-properties` package. It provides the missing module.

Comment: Thanks . how reinstalling ?

Comment: If you don't know how to reinstall a package, then you may not be prepared to manage PPAs yet, so make sure you maintain good backups of your data. Open a terminal: `sudo apt install --reinstall <package name>`

Comment: Thanks . i run `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-software-properties`   but Still the problem persists

Comment: Try to reinstall two other packages: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-apt python3-apt`.

Comment: @N0rbert .Thanks . but I run this but still the problem persists

Comment: Please add output of `which python` and `which python3` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert  . `which python : /usr/bin/python` . `which python3 : /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: After bit of search i found it to be problem is system is trying to find apt_pkg file for latest version of python than finding current version. So, renaming the concerned file seems a work-around. Details are given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg

Comment: I found this answer and worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44612200/1038565

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Its very late but could be helpful for others.

```
> cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
> sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Comment: I adapted this answer to use a symlink instead and this seemed to work too: `ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so`

Answer (score 22):

There was a similar question on 2014 ([Problem with update-manager: No module named 'apt_pkg' in Ubuntu 13.10, having installed Python 3.4 on /usr/local/lib](https://askubuntu.com/questions/480908/problem-with-update-manager-no-module-named-apt-pkg-in-ubuntu-13-10-having-i)). The solution worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-apt
sudo apt-get install python3-apt
```

Comment: Thanks . now I have bleow error : `sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found`

Comment: I am having the exactly same issue. Any fix?

Comment: Please do a `sudo apt install software-properties-common` after that, to get rid of the `sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found` error.

Comment: Removing python3-apt is fairly dangerous since it already removes import packages like ubuntu-desktop and xorg.

Comment: PLS heed the warning about the dangers of removing python3-apt.

Comment: @DavidMedinets what should I do if I'm such a dumbass and did that? :facepalm:

Comment: If you end up with `sudo do-release-upgrade 
sudo: do-release-upgrade: command not found` then it can be reinstalled with `sudo apt install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core`

Comment: we need to vote down this answer. I just messed up my system by following that advice!

Answer (score 20):

If you updated with a NEW python (e.g. dist had 3.5 but you installed 3.7), then your `/usr/bin/python3` points to a python that does not have `apt_pkg`.

edit `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository` where it says

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
```

to point to

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.5
```

(insert your distro python version, 3.5 for 16.04 or 3.6 for 18.04)

Comment: Checking the original python version for my Ubuntu version was key for me.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this; instead revert `/usr/bin/python3` to what it was before. I'm pretty sure other system scripts use `/usr/bin/python3` and `apt_pkg`, so this is only a bandage fix.

Answer (score 8):

Create a symbolic link at `apt_pkg.so` which references to file `apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution that worked for me for the latest `apt_pkg_cpython` package on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that worked for me was to uninstall python 3.5 and then install the apt tools again:

```
sudo apt remove python3.5*
sudo apt install python3-apt
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me. Firstly check the target `apt_pkg` library:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg*
```

it should return the following:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

where `35` stands for the `python` version. Set this version as default for `python3`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set python3 /usr/bin/python3.5
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this remove the alternatives

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python3
```

Then

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```