# CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator on ubuntu

Tags: apt, mysql, python3

after installing Python 3.7 and Mysql on Ubuntu 18 LTS, I am getting following error after firing command "sudo apt update"

```
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]      
Fetched 252 kB in 1s (334 kB/s)                                
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Now while installing any new software I am getting same error again and again.

Is there any solution on this?

Comment: Did You resolve this problem?

Comment: I didn’t tried the solution you mentioned because I moved to Ubuntu 19 where python 3 is default instead of python 2.7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt\_pkg' error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069087/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg-error)

Comment: Not worth trying to resolve it. I move to next Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 12):

You have problem with python-apt package.Try `sudo apt-get remove --purge python3-apt` and `sudo apt autoremove` then install: `apt-get install python3-apt`

Answer (score 4):

This may be because `/usr/bin/python3` symlink is not pointing to the Python3 version that ubuntu expects. Ubuntu 18.04 is presently on `3.6.9`.

To correct this you may need to re-create the symlink `/usr/bin/python3` to point to `/usr/bin/python3.6`.

If you cannot find the python3.6 executable or it does not execute correctly, you may need to purge and re-install `python3-apt` as per gongarek's comment.

I came across this today because last night I pointed `/usr/bin/python3` to my `Python 3.7` installation due to a cron issue. I use `Python 3.7` for all new code to leverage the futures feature (`from __future__ import print_function`) which is not supported in `Python 3.6`. This was an issue with cron jobs as `cron` was using `/usr/bin/python3` to execute the script which failed to execute. My work around now has to be explicitly specifying the correct path to the `python 3.7` executable.

With this cron issue, you would see in the cron execution stderr/stdout logging:

```
SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mem_check.py", line 20, in <module>
    import qcorelite as Q_
  File "/home/tquinn/_data/tqmain/sys/memory_check/qcorelite.py", line 1
    from __future__ import annotations, print_function
```

Comment: This was my exact issue. Thank you.

Comment: Cool. I have since moved away from touching the built-in Python that Ubuntu uses and using pyenv to manage my userland python scripts. It takes a bit of getting used to but has saved me a world of trouble mucking around in the Python that Ubuntu uses. Good Luck!