# do-release-upgrade 20.04->22.04 hangs, last main.log line is "running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)"

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

Starting with a PC happily running Ubuntu 18.04 desktop, I copied the entire drive as a backup, then tried to upgrade it to 22.04. Running do-release-upgrade brought it up to 20.04, and it seems happy running that. After a few reboots I tried upgrading it from 20.04 to 22.04. It always hangs in the same spot, right after:

```
Get:184 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [13.4 kB]
Get:185 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [480 B]
Get:186 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Fetched 504 MB in 6s (0 B/s)
```

The longest I've left it like that is at least a few hours. It's stuck. Control-C gets out of it, and the traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 27, in <module>
    col.create(db)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 95, in create
    self._fill_commands(con)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 140, in _fill_commands
    if sub.wait() != 0:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1083, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1806, in _wait
    (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1764, in _try_wait
    (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)
```

At work we have a VM that had the same problem, going from 20.04 to 22.04. In the end they wound up just making a fresh 22.04 VM. I do some work stuff on this PC, so it's possible some particular package is to blame and both systems had that package installed.

While it's in that state:

```
# tail -n 10 /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log
2023-04-02 12:29:04,801 DEBUG url_downloadable: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports//dists/jammy/Release
2023-04-02 12:29:04,801 DEBUG s='http' n='ports.ubuntu.com' p='/ubuntu-ports//dists/jammy/Release' q='' f=''
2023-04-02 12:29:04,980 DEBUG entry 'deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse' updated to new dist
2023-04-02 12:29:04,980 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse'
2023-04-02 12:29:04,980 DEBUG entry 'deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse' updated to new dist
2023-04-02 12:29:04,980 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse'
2023-04-02 12:29:04,980 DEBUG entry 'deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse' updated to new dist
2023-04-02 12:29:04,981 DEBUG examining: 'deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse'
2023-04-02 12:29:04,981 DEBUG entry 'deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse' updated to new dist
2023-04-02 12:29:04,986 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
```

I've tried a lot of different things suggested in other threads here. For example I moved all .list files from /etc/apt/ and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ that had anything but "focal" listed (some had been "bionic"). And for example I can run these commands after a reboot, and I get the same issue:

```
apt-get clean
apt --fix-broken install
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get clean
do-release-upgrade
```

> dpkg --print-architecture and dpkg  --print-foreign-architectures please edit your question for that.

```
scott@scott-XPS-8900:~$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
scott@scott-XPS-8900:~$ dpkg  --print-foreign-architectures
i386
arm64
```

The aforementioned work stuff involves compiling for arm64. I'm not sure why i386 is there (EDIT: "dpkg --list | grep i36" says "syslinux-legacy").

UPDATE: There are no longer any foreign architectures. I purged those packages and removed the i386 and arm64 architectures as described in [How to remove all i386 packages from Ubuntu 64bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113301/how-to-remove-all-i386-packages-from-ubuntu-64bit). No improvement.

> it looks for me something with python/python3 is broken. sudo apt update

Earlier on I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt
```

At the moment "apt update" is hanging. It wasn't doing that earlier:

```
scott@scott-XPS-8900:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
Hit:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
```

(then it just sits there) After a few minutes, control-C:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 27, in <module>
    col.create(db)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 95, in create
    self._fill_commands(con)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 140, in _fill_commands
    if sub.wait() != 0:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1083, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1806, in _wait
    (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1764, in _try_wait
    (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)
```

> Why are the ports.ubuntu.com repo still active?

It seems they're left over from when I previously had foreign architectures (i386, arm64) enabled. I commented them out in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and ran `apt update` again. It still hangs.

Then I tried:

```
sudo pkill cnf-update-db
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt update``
```

Again it hangs, and control-C produces the same stack trace as above.

After much digging through the Python code in the control-C backtrace and doing a bunch of searches, I found: [CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171386/commandnotfound-db-creator-import-dbcreator-on-ubuntu)

That got `apt-get update` going:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3-apt
sudo apt autoremove
apt-get install python3-apt
# Probably most of the next few commands weren't needed
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get update
```

I'll reboot and try `do-release-upgrade` again, and report back.(UPDATE: it worked -- see my posted solution)

Comment: `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg  --print-foreign-architectures` please [edit] your question for that.

Comment: Please addapt this to your situation for arm64 packages https://askubuntu.com/questions/113301/how-to-remove-all-i386-packages-from-ubuntu-64bit

Comment: it looks for me something with python/python3 is broken. `sudo apt update` please [edit] your question for output not as comment.

Comment: Why are the `ports.ubuntu.com` repo still active?

Comment: Please remove the solution from the question and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After the large number of things I tried (listed in the question), `do-release-upgrade` finally ran without hanging. My PC is now running Ubuntu 22.04.

My suspicion is that the purge and install of `python-apt` (which I got from [CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171386/commandnotfound-db-creator-import-dbcreator-on-ubuntu)) was the most important step, but it may have just been the *last* important step:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3-apt
sudo apt autoremove
apt-get install python3-apt
```

My original issue was solved, but `do-release-upgrade` reported some errors. I would suggest to anyone with the same problem I had that you do the `python3-apt` purge/install, then try `do-release-upgrade`, doing the other things I tried only if that doesn't work.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openmpi-bin
 mpi-default-bin
 libcoarrays-openmpi-dev:amd64
 libopenmpi-dev:amd64
 libboost-mpi-python1.74.0
 libboost-mpi-python1.74-dev
 libboost-mpi-python-dev
 libboost-all-dev
 mpi-default-dev
 libboost-mpi1.74-dev
 libboost-mpi-dev

Upgrade complete

The upgrade has completed but there were errors during the upgrade
process.
```

I resolved those thus (mainly based on [Problem with package installation - linux-image-server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378883/problem-with-package-installation-linux-image-server)):

```
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  openmpi-bin
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  mpi-default-bin
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  libcoarrays-openmpi-dev:amd64
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  libopenmpi-dev:amd64
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  libboost-mpi-python1.74.0
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  libboost-mpi-python1.74-dev
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  libboost-mpi-python-dev
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  libboost-all-dev
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  mpi-default-dev
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  libboost-mpi1.74-dev
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq  libboost-mpi-dev

# ... but one package was more stubborn, indicating:
# update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/mpi corrupt: slave link same as main link /usr/bin/mpicc
# Fixed with:
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all mpi
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/mpi
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq openmpi-bin

# then checking for errors:
apt autoremove
apt upgrade
```

All good now.