# theHarvester: failure to import modules

Tags: dependencies, python3, versions

I'm trying to install and run [theHarvester](https://github.com/laramies/theHarvester). I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

My default python3 is version 3.5.2. theHarvester requires Python3.6+, so I've installed Python3.6 and Python3.7 with `sudo apt install python3.6 pthon3.7`. My pip3 is version 8.1.1 (seems to be for python3.5).

I've run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` to install the dependencies. When I do `python3.6 theHarvester.py`, I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "theHarvester.py", line 10, in <module>
    from theHarvester import __main__
  File "/home/johnzhau/myTools/theHarvester/theHarvester/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gevent import monkey as curious_george
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gevent'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "theHarvester.py", line 10, in <module>
    from theHarvester import __main__
  File "/home/johnzhau/myTools/theHarvester/theHarvester/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gevent import monkey as curious_george
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gevent'
```

Apparently, installing the dependencies with pip3 v8.1.1 doesn't let python3.6 use the dependencies. How should I fix it so that either I can install dependencies for python 3.6+ or let python3.6 read pip3 v8.1.1 (python3.5)'s dependencies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt\_pkg' error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069087/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg-error)

Answer (score 0):

[theHarvester](https://www.nmmapper.com/kalitools/theharvester/email-harvester-tool/online/) should be fairely easy to install try this

```
pip3 install gevent
```

As for apt_pgk try this

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt
```