# sudo apt update throwing a fuzzy error?

Tags: apt

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
      from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", 
  line 11, in <module>
      import apt_pkg
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
  Error in sys.excepthook:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, 
  in apport_excepthook
      from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in 
 <module>
     from apport.report import Report
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in 
  <module>
      import apport.fileutils
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in 
  <module>
      from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", 
  line 11, in <module>
      import apt_pkg
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
  Reading package lists... Done
  E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if 
  /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update- 
 db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
  E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: That does not look like a fuzzy error. That looks like you changed the version of Python3, which broke apt.

Comment: yes i changed it to python 3.7 but how can i fix that and keep using python 3.7?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt\_pkg' error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069087/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg-error)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about how to upgrade Python3 without breaking `apt` as mentioned in comments by @user535733. You can just install several versions of python in parallel on your machine.

You can easily fond tutorials for that:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-python-versions-and-virtual-environments-venv-pyenv-pyvenv-a29fb00c296f/